# Passing superclass object as parameter to subclass constructor (java)

Tags: java, inheritance

I've done a bit of searching, but I'm either not asking the right question or not remembering correctly.  In any case, in Java, I am wondering if it is possible to pass the super class object in as a parameter to a subclass and what the most efficient way of making that object's data available to the class's super class.

Code examples:

```
public class superclass {
  String myparm1;
  String myParm2;
  int myParmN;

  public superclass(String p1, String p2, int pn)
  {
    this.myparm1 = p1;
    this.myparm2 = p2;
    this.myParmN = pn;
  }
  // other methods here
}

public class subclass extends superclass {
  double b1;
  double b2;

  public subclass(superclass sc, double b1, double b2) {
    // easy way to make sc data available to this class?
    // Do I create a copy or clone method, or some other way?
    // calling super(sc); wouldn't exactly work 
    this.b1 = b1;
    this.b2 = b2;
  }
}
```

if I had a constructor in superclass that was `public superclass(superclass sc) { // assign sc properties to this properties, correct? }` then I could simply use `super(sc);`

Comment: If the superclass constructor expects two Strings and an int, you must call super() with 2 Strings and an int. There's no way around it. If these 3 values are exposed by `sc`, then get them, and apsss them to super().

Comment: Why don't you `super(sc.p1, sc.p2, sc.p3)`?

Comment: `superclass(superclass sc)`? Calling `super(sc)` wouldn't even work then because there isn't an `Object` constructor with `superclass` as a parameter

Comment: Raffaele. Of course, with a small number of properties, that's easy. But supposing my class has a large number of properties.  (It may be bad design in that instance, of course, but I digress.)

Comment: @Machtyn - If your superclass has a large number of properties, it becomes more important to encapsulate the details of copying it. Can you add a copy constructor in the `superclass` class, of the form you note at the end of your question -- `public superclass(superclass sc)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no point to passing in a reference to the superclass of an object in the constructor. Your subclass is already an instance of the superclass.

Even though you can't directly see the private components of the superclass, but they still exist and calls to public accessor methods will still produce normal behavior.

In answer to your second question, the most efficient way to access the data inside the parent class is with the accessor methods of that parent class. If it has get/set properties methods that populate some data structure full of properties, just call those methods from your child class and they'll work exactly the same as they did for the parent. Now, if those internal data structures are populated by the constructor of the parent class, you'll have to invoke that constructor with the correct methods when you create an instance of the child constructor that needs them- typically by calling the appropriate super() at the beginning of the child's constructor.

If you're trying to get around the restriction that you can't see the private parts of the superclass, java intentionally doesn't let you do that. You can get around this with reflection unless you're stuck inside an execution environment that disallows this, but I generally wouldn't consider this a safe or elegant approach.

From comment below, I understand what the OP is trying to do and this should work, though obviously it depends upon your ability to make changes to the super class:

```
public class Super
{
    public Super (Super other)
    {
        //copy stuff from other to this
    }
}

public class Child extends Super
{
    public Child (Super other)
    {
        super(other);
        //continue constructor
    }

}
```

Comment: From the OP's text, with added emphasis: "pass the super class *object*".

Comment: So you're trying to figure out a way to take an already instantiated instance of the super class, pass it to the constructor of a child class and use that parent instance as part of the initialization that takes place in the child's constructor?

Comment: Correct, Jim. An already instantiated instance.  And, I agree with your last statement. If my superclass has private data that is unexposed (and needs to remain that way), it would be bad design for the copy constructor to try and reflect that data out.

Comment: Unless the superclass is written to explicitly enable this to happen (ie a constructor that takes another instance of the same class and copies over the parts), it's not something that java naturally supports.  You could accomplish this with something like public Super (Super super) (//copy over fields from super to this) and then in the child class you'd have something like this public Child (Super super) {super(super); ....}

Answer (score 2):

You can't. When you build an object with Java (for example with `new`), that instance has a class, and that class has a parent (possibly Object).

The parent-child relation only holds between classes, not between objects! No object has a *parent object* (at least, not at the language level) - so you can't accept the parent in the contructor and store it in some Java-defined place.

However your domain can have parent and child entities, in which case you need fields or data structures to store the links between them.

Comment: It sounds like the OP has a `superclass` object, and wants to use it to initialize the superclass part of a new `subclass` object. That is feasible, given a suitable superclass constructor.

Comment: But then he can simply use `super(arg.p1, arg.p2, ...)` - I already asked that in my comment to the original question

Answer (score 0):

To answer a previous question, suppose the superclass has large number of properties.  In that case, the design of the class may be bad, of course.

Perhaps the best answer is:

```
public class superclass {
  // properties and constructors as defined in OP

  public void copy(superclass sc) {
    this.myParm1 = sc.getMyParm1();
    this.myParm2 = sc.getMyParm2();
    this.myParmN = sc.getMyParmN();
  }

  // other methods as needed
}
```

That way, the sub class can just call the `super.copy(sc)`.  Of course, I would need another constructor in superclass that will set defaults: `public superclass() { // set defaults }`

So subclass could be:

```
public class subclass extends superclass {
  //properties as defined in OP

  public subclass(superclass sc, double b1, double b2) {
    this.b1 = b1;
    this.b2 = b2;
    super.copy(sc);
  }
}
```

In this way, I'm only having to type those parameters out, and any subclasses that would want to accept a superclass object won't have to define that structure each and every time. (less typing, less chance for mistake or forgetting something.)

Comment: The copy() method helps if you want to copy into an existing object. But your examples are about construction. For construction, it's better to offer a constructor. (And if instances are immutable, it's necessary.) If you want to support both copy construction and copy assign, you can provide both a constructor and a method, and optionally share an implementation between them.

Comment: Andy, thank you for pointing me in the right direction and finally asking the right question.

Copy constructors: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12